# Mule application configured with ActiveMQ to be deployed in cloudhub

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic, cloudhub

I have integrated JMS using ActiveMQ in one of my Mule application. I want to deploy it in cloudhub.

Could you please help me for the following queries:

- For deploying the application with ActiveMQ configured JMS does it required anything groundwork to be done before deployment? (such as ActiveMQ is to be installed and configured for my CH account?)
- For time being I have configured the ActiveMQ which is already installed in OnPremise server and is being used from cloudHub deployed application. Is it a proper or standard way to use externally installed ActiveMQ?

Appreciate the quick and best answer for the above queries.

Thank you,
Best Regards,
Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

you have already installed MQ service on your server side, you can use those credentials to configure your mule MQ adapter through mule properties file same as like you are using with local runtime
e.g.

```
mq.host=
mq.port=
mq.vhost=
mq.username=
mq.password=
```

CloudHub will connect to your on premise MQ service. Your approach is correct and no any MQ specific groundwork required.